# Why is NSOperation::completionBlock called too soon?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a very simple asynchronous operation

```
@interface IDBWebpValidationOperation()

@property BOOL executing;
@property BOOL finished;

@end

@implementation IDBWebpValidationOperation

@synthesize executing;
@synthesize finished;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.completionBlock = ^{
        NSDLog(@"webp validation has finished");
    };
}
return self;
}

- (void)main
{
IDBAssert0(self.bestCapture.webpCandidate);

self.finished = NO;
if(self.postProcessingValidator) {
    self.executing = YES;
    // this starts async operation, see callback below
    self.postProcessingValidator(self.bestCapture.webpCandidate);
}else{
    IDBAssert0(0);
    //      self.bestCapture.jpegNSData = self.bestCapture.webpCandidate;
    IDBAssert0(self.bestCapture.jpegNSData);
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished = YES;
}
}

- (void)scanningViewController:    (UIViewController<PPScanningViewController>*)scanningViewController
          didOutputResults:(NSArray*)results
{
if([results count]>0) {
    self.bestCapture.jpegNSData = self.bestCapture.webpCandidate;
    IDBAssert0(self.bestCapture.jpegNSData);
}else{
    IDBAssert0(self.microblinkFailureHandler);
    self.microblinkFailureHandler();
}
IDBAssert0(!self.finished);
self.executing = NO;
self.finished = YES;
}

-(BOOL)isAsynchronous
{
return YES;    //Default is NO so overriding it to return YES;
}
```

Here I have synthesized two atomic properties executing & finished
to avoid lots of (in my opinion dumb & extraneous) code swift would force you to do for KVO and the synthesided atomic properties would get me out of the box
(I think).

The issue is completionBlock is called before scanningViewController:
callback is invoked. Why?????

This is on ios 9.3.x in case this matters

Comment: Maybe the dumb and extraneous code is what makes NSOperation actually work :-(

Comment: Yeah, spelling the getter and the setter to KVO spec did resolve this.